# Passar List como parâmetro de expressão LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lista, parâmetros

Tenho uma expressão LINQ em que o resultado é salvo na variável *query*, que é transformada em lista, esta *query* retorna uma série de atributos "RA".

Gostaria de passar essa lista de atributos como parâmetro na expressão LINQ resultada na `query2`. Quero que a `query2` me retorne todos os códigos de disciplina em que esses "RA" estão relacionados(Sim, quero passar todos eles de uma vez).

Fiz da forma abaixo porém não obtive resultados, o código compilou, mas não funcionou. Como passo a lista `query` como parâmetro no `where`? Devo converter essa lista de 1 um único atributo para um tipo comum? Como faço?

```
void cargarDados(Int32 disc)
    {
       List<Turma> turmas = db.GetCollection<Turma>("turma").FindAll().ToList();

        var query = (from t in turmas
                     where t.COD_DISCIPLINA == disc
                     select new
                     {
                         t.RA                            

                     }).ToList();




        var query2 = (from t1 in turmas
                      where t1.COD_DISCIPLINA.Equals(query)
                      select new
                      {
                          t1.COD_DISCIPLINA
                      }).ToList();


        dataGridView1.DataSource = query2;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cargarDados(1);
}

void cargarDados(Int32 disc)
{
    List<Turmas> turmas = new List<Turmas>();// db.GetCollection("turma").FindAll().ToList();
    Turmas turma = new Turmas();
    turma.RA = 1;
    turma.COD_DISCIPLINA = 1;
    turmas.Add(turma);

    Turmas turma1 = new Turmas();
    turma1.RA = 2;
    turma1.COD_DISCIPLINA = 1;
    turmas.Add(turma1);

//----------------------------------------------------------------//
    var RA = turmas
        .Where(t => t.COD_DISCIPLINA == disc)
        .Select(t => t.RA).ToList();

    var query2 = turmas
        .Where(t => RA.Contains(t.COD_DISCIPLINA))
         .Select(t => new
         {
             t.COD_DISCIPLINA,
         })
         .ToList();
//-------------------------------------------------------------//
}
```

---

```
class Turmas
{
    public Int32 COD_DISCIPLINA { get; set; }
    public Int32 RA { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Marconcilio, funfou, e com boa performance ! Valeu

Answer (score 2):

Perceba que quando você faz um `new { t1.RA }`, você na verdade está criando um novo tipo anônimo que não te dará o resultado desejado ao comparar com o tipo da propriedade `COD_DISCIPLINA`.

Como sugestão final, sugiro fazer tudo em uma query só:

```
    var query2 = (from t1 in turmas
                  where (from t in turmas
                         where t.COD_DISCIPLINA == disc
                         select t.RA).Contains(t1.COD_DISCIPLINA)
                  select new
                  {
                      t1.COD_DISCIPLINA
                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: Obrigado Jônatas, aqui funfou

Answer (score 1):

Faz assim:

```
void cargarDados(Int32 disc)
        {
            List turmas = db.GetCollection("turma").FindAll().ToList();


        var query = (from t in turmas
                     where t.COD_DISCIPLINA == disc
                     select new
                     {
                         t.RA                            

                     }).ToList();




        var query2 = (from t1 in turmas
                      where query.Contains(t1.COD_DISCIPLINA)
                      select new
                      {
                          t1.COD_DISCIPLINA
                      }).ToList();


        dataGridView1.DataSource = query2;

    }
```